# Создайте цикл, который в зависимости от кратности числа будет применять к нему разные математические операции. Число целое от m до n

Tags: javascript, циклы, числа, условия

Объявите переменную m, которая содержит целое число больше нуля
Объявите переменную n, которая содержит целое число больше m и <= 50
m и n не должны меняться в процессе работы программы
Граничные числа m и n должны включаться в рассчет
Результат должен храниться в переменной result
Выполните действия ниже - порядок важен
Если число кратно 2 но не кратно 4, то прибавьте его к результату
Если число кратно 3, то отнимите его от результата
Если число кратно 4, то умножте его на результат
Если число кратно 5, то просто выведите в консоль это число и не изменяйте результат (даже если число подпадает под условия выше)
Если число не попадает под условия выше, то пропускаем его
Число должно попадать только под ОДНО условие. Если число пападает под несколько условий - выполнится должно первое из них
Начальное значение для вычислений возьмите 0
Значение result в консоль не выводим

Получилса такой код но он работаеть не правильно.Выводить не все числа кратные 5.
И не правильно считает результат.Можете подсказать что делаю не так

```
 const m = 5;
 const n = 15;
 let result = 0;
 for(let i = m;i <=n; i++) {
     if(i % 2 === 0) {
        result= result+i;
      }else if (i % 3 ===0) {
       result = result - i;
      } else if(i % 4 === 0) {
       result = result * i;
      } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
       console.log(i);
        }
      }
```

Comment: *Если число кратно 2 но не кратно 4* - где у вас это условие?

Comment: в самом начале if(i % 2 === 0)

Comment: Но у вас там одно условие, где часть, что `но не кратно 4 `?

Comment: _Выводить не все числа кратные 5_ -  5 выводит, но 10 подпадает под условие `i % 2 === 0`, a 15 под `i % 3 === 0`

Comment: Можно `i % 4 == 2`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JS задача с циклом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207345/js-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

`(даже если число подпадает под условия выше)`, похоже, должно исполняться так:
(см. также реализацию `кратно 2 но не кратно 4`)

```
(i % 5 === 0)
{
    console.log(i);
}
else {
  if((i % 2 === 0) && (i % 4 != 0)) {
    result= result+i;
  }else if (i % 3 ===0) {
   result = result - i;
  } else if(i % 4 === 0) {
   result = result * i;
  }
```

Comment: Cпасибо!!!Большое